# How to add other field which related to many-to-many inline admin on Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-admin

I have Transaction model and Match model which has many-to-many field relationship

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=16, decimal_places=2)
    card_no = CleanTextField(null=True, blank=True)
    date = models.DateField()

class Match(models.Model):
    match_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    a_transactions = models.ManyToManyField(Transaction, related_name="a_matches")
    b_transactions = models.ManyToManyField(Transaction, related_name="b_matches")
```

And also have admin inline and model admin

```
class ATransactionInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Transaction.a_matches.through
    extra = 0 

class BTransactionInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Transaction.b_matches.through
    extra = 0 


class TransactionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin): 
    list_display = ["amount", "date"]
    inlines = [ATransactionInline, BTransactionInline]


admin.site.register(Transaction, TransactionAdmin)
```

So in Transaction admin page there're display the match object in inlines
But I need to display a and b transactions which related to that match object
Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question properly, you can override `get_queryset` in each inline, and filter what you want:

```py
class ATransactionInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Transaction.a_matches.through
    extra = 0
    verbose_name = "A Transaction"
    verbose_name_plural = "A Transactions"

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        queryset = super().get_queryset(request)
        return queryset.filter(transaction__in=self.parent_obj.a_matches.all())

class BTransactionInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Transaction.b_matches.through
    extra = 0
    verbose_name = "B Transaction"
    verbose_name_plural = "B Transactions"

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        queryset = super().get_queryset(request)
        return queryset.filter(transaction__in=self.parent_obj.b_matches.all())

class TransactionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["amount", "date"]
    inlines = [ATransactionInline, BTransactionInline]

admin.site.register(Transaction, TransactionAdmin)
```